# How can I change the text of a button based on click if is looped inside a map function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am mapping over a series of cards in a form component like this :

````
```

{links?.map((i,j) => (
  <main className={styles["card-container"]} key={j}>
    <Card
        url={i?.url}
        shortenUrl={i?.shorten}
    />
  </main>
))}

```
````

That `Card` renders a URL link, a shortened link and a button that says "click"

```
<div>
  <div>{url}</div>
  <div>{shortenUrl}</div>
  <Button>Copy</Button>

</div>
```

The `Button` too is a reusable component,

```
  return (
    <>
      <button>{children}</button>
    </>
  )
```

What I want to do:

- I want to click the button on any of the mapped cards, and the button text should be changed to "copied"

what I have tried :

- I have tried using a state to change the text, but it changes "copy" -> "copied" on all the mapped cards.
- I also tried passing props from the `form` component using prop drilling to the Button component, but it doesn't work as expected.
- I looked at other answers here on SO, one answer was to use button text as an array itself, but I'm not sure how to implement it in this context.

Any solution to this?

Thanks for reading this far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add local state to each `Card` component, create a local click handler that toggles the state and calls any passed `onClick` handlers.

Example:

```
const [copy, setCopy] = useState();

const clickHandler = (e) => {
  setCopy(copy => !copy);
  // call any external click handler, pass onClick event object, etc...
};

<div>
  <div>{url}</div>
  <div>{shortenUrl}</div>
  <Button onClick={clickHandler}>
    {copy ? "Copied" : "Copy"}
  </Button>
</div>
```

### Update

If you want only a single selected button at-a-time, then lift the state to the parent component render the `Card` components and pass as props the currently selected card and a callback to toggle the selected card.

Example:

```
const [selected, setSelected] = React.useState(null);

const toggleSelected = index => {
  // toggle null if deselecting current selected,
  // otherwise set selected as new index
  setSelected(selected => selected === index ? null : index);
};

...

{links?.map((i, index) => (
  <main className={styles["card-container"]} key={index}>
    <Card
      url={i?.url}
      shortenUrl={i?.shorten}
      selected={selected === index}
      onClick={() => toggleSelected(index)}
    />
  </main>
))}
```

...

```
const Card = ({ url, shortenUrl, selected, onClick }) => {
  ...

  return (
    ...

    <div>
      <div>{url}</div>
      <div>{shortenUrl}</div>
      <Button onClick={onClick}>
        {selected ? "Copied" : "Copy"}
      </Button>
    </div>

    ...
  );
};
```

Comment: Very neat solution! Once a button is clicked on a first card, how do I revert it back to "copy" when the second button is set to "copied"?

Comment: @anshul Ah, if you want only one button "selected" at-a-time, then the state should be lifted to the parent and you save a "selected" id or index and pass this to `Card` as a prop and check if the currently mapped card's button is the "selected" one and set the text. Does this make sense?  I can update answer and provide an example if needed.

Comment: yeah, that is exactly my use case, could you please provide an example?

Comment: @anshul I've updated my answer and added a second second. Please check it out.

Comment: Amazing! works like a charm, thanks